# Expand script for multiple columns

Tags: arrays, google-apps-script, google-sheets, checkbox

I'm new with these kind of things so sorry for the mistakes. I'm trying to use this script to remove checkboxes from a column everytime that the value in other columns is 0. The script is the following:

```
function onEdit() {var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet2"); //change this to the name of your sheetui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();

var names = ss.getRange("C1:C");

var namesValues = names.getValues(); //Get array of all the names

var checkboxes = ss.getRange("B1:B");

var cbRows = checkboxes.getHeight(); //Get # of rows in the rangesvar cbValues = checkboxes.getValues(); //Get array of all the checkbox column cell values//Logger.log(cbValues);

var newCBValues = new Array(cbRows); //Create an array to store all the new checkboxes values before we edit the actual spreadsheet

for (var row = 0; row < cbRows; row++) {
    newCBValues[row] = new Array(0); // Make the array 2 dimensional (even though it only has 1 column, it must be 2D).
    if (namesValues[row] == "0" || namesValues[row] == " ") { //If the name cell of this row is empty or blank then...
      newCBValues[row][0] = " "; //Set the value to one space (which will make the cell NOT true or false, and thus NOT display a checkbox).
      //Logger.log("newCBValues[" + row + "][0]: " + newCBValues[row][0]);
    }else{ //otherwise, if the name cell isn't blank...
      if (cbValues[row][0] === true) {
        newCBValues[row][0] = true; //Keep the checkbox checked if it's already checked
      }else{ //If the name cell isn't blank, and it's not true...
        newCBValues[row][0] = false; //Then Keep it or set it to False (an empty checkbox):
        
      }   
    }
  }
  checkboxes.setDataValidation(SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireCheckbox()).setValues(newCBValues);
  
}
```

If in var names = ss.getRange("C1:C") I select only one column it works. But when I want to set it for more columns (eg C1:E) it doesn't work.

Hope you can help me. THANKS!!!!

EDIT:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1MjIuZbON_nlaENqyARt_UnQZZ-ooZOMLjKmDM-nZl4M/edit#gid=1464332245

this is the file where I'm trying. Sheet 2. you can see from the apps script what changes if instead of var names = ss.getRange ("C1:C") I write (C1:E). Try it by yourself (see the differences of the column of checkboxes). THANK YOU!!!!

EDIT 2:

[This is the input (before running the script)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dEAXl.png)

[This is what I want (cell with 1 to have the checkboxes and cell with 0 not to have it)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lAw2Z.png)

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your question. In order to correctly understand your question, can you provide the sample input and output situations you expect as the image?

Comment: Please provide an image of what you have and explain what you want it to look like after the script runs.

Comment: Thank you for replying and adding more information. But, I cannot understand which is the sample input and output situations you expect. And, it seems that your script is different from your provided images. So I cannot understand what you want to do. I apologize for this. But I would like to support you. So can you provide the detail of your question? By this, I would like to try to understand your question.

Comment: @Cooper I wrote a link where you can access the script

Comment: @Tanaike I'm sorry for not being too clear. I put a link where you can see the file and the script. Sheet2

Comment: Thank you for replying. Your sample Spreadsheet is the sample input situation? In order to correctly understand your question, can you provide the sample input and output situations you expect as the image?

Comment: Thank you for replying. In your goal, when the values of the columns "A" and "B" are `1`, you want to put the checkbox to the column "D". Is my understanding correct?

Comment: @Tanaike Exactly!!! But with the script I can only with one column, if I add 2 columns checkboxes appear everywhere

Comment: Thank you for replying. From yor reply, I proposed a sample script as an answer. Could you please confirm it? If that was not useful, I apologize.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your provided sample input and output situations, I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to put the checkboxes to column "D" when the columns "A" and "B" are `1`.

In this case, how about the following sample script? From your showing script, in your situation, you might want to run the script by the script editor. So in this modification, the event object is not used.

#### Sample script:

```
function onEdit() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet2");
  var values = sheet.getRange("A1:B" + sheet.getLastRow()).getValues();
  var rangeList = values.map((r, i) => r.every(e => e == 1) ? `D${i + 1}` : "").filter(String);
  sheet.getRangeList(rangeList).insertCheckboxes();
}
```

#### Note:

- This sample script is for your provided sample Spreadsheet. So when you changed the Spreadsheet, the script might not be able to be used. Please be careful this.

#### References:

- [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)
- [getRangeList(a1Notations)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangelista1notations)

### Added:

When I had asked whether my understanding of `In your goal, when the values of the columns "A" and "B" are 1, you want to put the checkbox to the column "D". Is my understanding correct?` is correct, you said `Exactly!!!`. But, from your following reply,

> This was very useful for my example but as you also said, it does't work on my original file. I changed some values in the sheet to make it more similar to what I actually have

> I want to add checkboxes on B where C, D and E have 1

If you want to put the checkboxes when the columns "C", "D" and "E" are `1`, the sample script is as follows.

#### Sample script:

```
function onEdit() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet2");
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
  var values = sheet.getRange("C1:E" + lastRow).getValues();
  sheet.getRange("B1:B" + lastRow).removeCheckboxes();
  var rangeList = values.map((r, i) => r.every(e => e == 1) ? `B${i + 1}` : "").filter(String);
  sheet.getRangeList(rangeList).insertCheckboxes();
}
```

Comment: This was very useful for my example but as you also said, it does't work on my original file. I changed some values in the sheet to make it more similar to what I actually have

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1MjIuZbON_nlaENqyARt_UnQZZ-ooZOMLjKmDM-nZl4M/edit#gid=1535238536

Comment: I want to add checkboxes on B where C, D and E have 1

Comment: @Gaia Blandino Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. When I had asked whether my understanding of `In your goal, when the values of the columns "A" and "B" are 1, you want to put the checkbox to the column "D". Is my understanding correct?` is correct, you said `Exactly!!!`. So I had believed that my understanding was correct. But it seems that this is not correct. I deeply apologize for my poor English skill. From your reply, I added one more sample script. Could you please confirm it?

Comment: sorry I swear it's the last change. It's not your fault I think I'm not explaining me well. The script works but only when columns C D and E have 1. How can I do if I want to have checkbox when columns C OR D OR E have 1?

Comment: @Gaia Blandino Thank you for replying. I couldn't notice that you have one more request in your question. I deeply apologize for my poor English skill again. About your new request of `How can I do if I want to have checkbox when columns C OR D OR E have 1?`, in this case, how about modifying `var rangeList = values.map((r, i) => r.every(e => e == 1) ? `B${i + 1}` : "").filter(String);` to `var rangeList = values.map((r, i) => r.some(e => e == 1) ? `B${i + 1}` : "").filter(String);`? If I misunderstood your new request, I apologize again.